# Shortening ng-class values

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

Is there any terser way to write this:

```
ng-class="{ 'red': (percent < 0), 'green': (percent > 0), 'glyphicon-arrow-down': (percent < 0), 'glyphicon-arrow-up': (percent > 0) }"
```

I find myself writing a lot of these overly long `ng-class` attribute expressions.

Comment: my 5 cents why not work it out also in the css I mean for red glyphicon-arrow-down': (percent < 0) you could set up a class glyphicon-arrow-down-red and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the classes of like conditions.

```
ng-class="{ 'red glyphicon-arrow-down': (percent < 0), 'green glyphicon-arrow-up': (percent > 0) }"
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe taking out parenthesis like :

```
ng-class="{ 'red': percent < 0, 
            'green': percent > 0, 
            'glyphicon-arrow-down': percent < 0, 
            'glyphicon-arrow-up': percent > 0 }"
```